# In which Year do they teach Apparition?

Tags: harry-potter

When Harry Potter apparated (alongside Dumbledore) for the first time, he was already near the end of 6th year and it wasn't an academic lesson.

Do they teach Apparition in the last year? Or, Apparition wasn't in the syllabus at all?

Comment: -1 - this question shows zero research efforts

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Apparition is taught to students in their sixth year by a Ministry instructor. It's not part of the regular Hogwarts curriculum, but is an extra class available to students who wish to prepare for the Apparition exam when they turn 17.

> When Harry Potter apparated (alongside Dumbledore) for the first time, he was already near the end of 6th year and it wasn't his academic lesson.

This is incorrect. Harry Side-Along Apparates with Dumbledore twice at the start of the sixth book; from Privet Drive to wherever Horace Slughorn was hiding out and then from there to The Burrow.

Comment: Oh sorry. First apparition was at the beginning.

Answer (score 10):

They teach it in the 6th year as an optional class and the applicant may take the test as soon as they turn 17. It doesn't show this in the film version, but it's in the book.

He apparates with Dumbledore via side-along apparition at the beginning of the book, when visiting Horace Slughorn to convince him to come back to Hogwarts.

> The new term started next morning with a pleasant surprise for the
> sixth-years: a large sign had been pinned to the common-room notice
> boards overnight.
>
> Apparition Lessons
>
> If you are seventeen years of age, or will turn seventeen on or before
> 31st August, you are eligible for a twelve-week course of Apparition
> Lessons from a Ministry of Magic Apparition Instructor. Please sign
> below if you would like to participate. Cost: 12 Galleons.
>
> *The Half-Blood Prince; A Sluggish Memory*

Comment: Means, when Dumbledore apparated Harry alongside with him, it wasn't Harry's first time? Or, Harry bunked class?

Comment: Also, could you please add quotes from the books..

Comment: Harry apparated via side-along apparition a few times throughout HBP, I'll add some quotes now, I didn't have the books with me at the time of answering.

Comment: Both the age involved, and the fact that it’s a government-administrated qualification not a standard school course, happen to remarkably align with the driving licence situation for muggles (in the UK, at least).

Comment: but remember, 17 is the wizarding world's version of coming of age (i.e. British muggles' 18) so while it is the same as the age for a driving licence, it can also just be the same as getting it at the age of adulthood.